# Realtime audio stream from outpud device to input device ( from system mixer to microphone )

Tags: c#, naudio

I need to stream my OS mixer sound to the microphone. (to transfer them both via skype).
Important thing is -- I need to have ability to configure delay/latency of the stream.

**(VAC) Virtual Audio Cable is not solution for me:** it doesn't work in my case. I have an external USB sound device an app doesn't work for me. I have tried it. Truly.

I google it more than 2 days and found nothing.
So I want to try wrote my own app for this. Have no experience with NAudio.

At the moment all I have is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using NAudio.Wave;

namespace SoundApp
{
    public class AudioCable
    {
        private WaveOut _wvOut = null;

        private DirectSoundOut _output = null;
        private WaveIn _sourceStreamIn = null;
        private WaveOut _sourceStreamOut = null;

        public void InitDevices(string fromDevice, string toDevice)
        {
            Dispose();

            _sourceStreamIn = new WaveIn();
            _sourceStreamOut = new WaveOut();
            _output = new DirectSoundOut();

            if (fromDevice.Contains("INPUT"))
            {
                var tmp = fromDevice.Split('|')[0].Replace("INPUT: ", "").Trim(' ');
                int tmpDeviceNumber = int.Parse(tmp);
                _sourceStreamIn.DeviceNumber = tmpDeviceNumber;
            }
            else
            {
                var tmp = toDevice.Split('|')[0].Replace("OUTPUT: ", "").Trim(' ');
                int tmpDeviceNumber = int.Parse(tmp);
                _sourceStreamOut.DeviceNumber = tmpDeviceNumber;
            }

            Guid deviceGuid;
            if (toDevice.Contains("INPUT"))
            {
                var tmp = toDevice.Split('|')[0].Replace("INPUT: ", "").Trim(' ');
                int tmpDeviceNumber = int.Parse(tmp);
                WaveInCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(tmpDeviceNumber);
                deviceGuid = deviceInfo.ManufacturerGuid;
            }
            else
            {
                var tmp = toDevice.Split('|')[0].Replace("OUTPUT: ", "").Trim(' ');
                int tmpDeviceNumber = int.Parse(tmp);
                WaveOutCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveOut.GetCapabilities(tmpDeviceNumber);
                deviceGuid = deviceInfo.ManufacturerGuid;
            }
            _output = new DirectSoundOut(deviceGuid);
        }

        public void PlaySound()
        {
            WaveInProvider waveIn = null;

            if (_sourceStreamIn != null)
            {
                waveIn = new WaveInProvider(_sourceStreamIn);
            }
            else if (_sourceStreamOut != null)
            {
                throw new Exception("Sorry, not supported right now");
                //waveIn = new WaveInProvider(_sourceStreamOut);
            }

            _output.Init(waveIn);
            _output.Play();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _sourceStreamIn = null;
            _sourceStreamOut = null;

            if (_output != null)
            {
                if (_output.PlaybackState == PlaybackState.Playing)
                {
                    _output.Stop();
                }

                _output.Dispose();
                _output = null;
            }
        }

        public string[] GetAudioDevices()
        {
            var devices = new List<string>();

            for (int i = 0; i < WaveIn.DeviceCount; i++)
            {
                WaveInCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveIn.GetCapabilities(i);
                devices.Add($"INPUT: {i}     | {deviceInfo.ProductName}");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < WaveOut.DeviceCount; i++)
            {
                WaveOutCapabilities deviceInfo = WaveOut.GetCapabilities(i);
                devices.Add($"OUTPUT: {i} | {deviceInfo.ProductName}");
            }

            return devices.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

And the form source:

```
namespace SoundApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        AudioCable _ac = new AudioCable();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cBoxSource.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
            cBoxTarget.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;

            cBoxSource.Items.AddRange(_ac.GetAudioDevices());
            cBoxTarget.Items.AddRange(_ac.GetAudioDevices());
        }

        private void btnStartStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _ac.InitDevices(cBoxSource.SelectedItem.ToString(), cBoxTarget.SelectedItem.ToString());
            _ac.PlaySound();
        }
    }
}
```

So at the first I'm trying to stream microphone to the sound output device.... And it does not work at all.

So My questions is:

1. There are no microphone sound and I'm do not understand why so. Code is valid and dont throw any errors.
2. Looks like there is no ability to stream outputDevice sound stream to the inputDevice with NAudio. Is there exist some hack for this?

Comment: How someone with 1025 of reputation can ask something like this here?

Comment: @Gusman you have an experience in all of PC science directions, don't you? But I have not. I have answered a lot of times on the topics where I have an experience. But I have no exp in work with audiostreamings. If it so easy, please, answer how to do this.

Comment: No, what I meant is that this question type is totally forbidden on S.O. No code, no concrete programming problem, nothing, you are asking for some tutorials (external resources) or someone to write the code for you, both against the rules of S.O. Nobody will criticize someone for not knowing something, that's why stackoverflow exists, to get help when you have a problem or you don't know something. But something _concrete_.

Comment: @Gusman , added :) Sorry, long time didnt work with stackowerflow :)

Comment: Holly molly dude!! That's totally different!! Now is a perfect valid question :)

Comment: See these alternatives : http://www.dxzone.com/5-free-virtual-audio-cable-software/ (before digging in code)

Comment: jack -- did't understand how to work with it. All of other is for another OS's.

Comment: NAudio cannot do this. It is simply a limitation of Windows. You have to use some kind of virtual audio cable to achieve what you are asking.